# Авторизация на сайте через mail.ru

Tags: javascript, request, oauth

Доброго времени суток!

На сайте реализую получение OAuth токена доступа от mail.ru и наткнулся на проблему, что после авторизации и подтверждения прав этот mail.ru перенаправляет пользователя на свой url "http://connect.mail.ru/oauth/success.html#expires_in=00000&refresh_token=0000&access_token=0000&token_type=bearer&x_mailru_vid=0000", хотя я передаю при запросе redirect_uri.

Тестирую с локального компа по ip адресу 192.168..... и есть подозрение, что в этом всё дело, но если кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить!

Answer (score 1):

Да, скорее всего, это из-за того, что тестирование происходит с локальной машины. В интернете пишут такие способы:

```
https://connect.mail.ru/oauth/authorize?
client_id=идентификатор вашего сайта&
response_type=token&
redirect_uri=адрес принимающей страницы на вашем сайте
```

В значении параметра redirect_uri передайте адрес страницы, на которую будет происходить перенаправление пользователя после авторизации. Эта страница должна находиться на домене вашего сайта.

code — используйте если вам нужен доступ к API и данным пользователя только с серверной части вашего сайта

token — используйте, если вам нужен доступ к API только из JavaScript, например, если у вас веб-приложение, полностью работающее внутри браузера пользователя

code_and_token — если вам нужен доступ к API и из серверной части сайта, и из JavaScript, используйте этот вариант

**
Если вы указали response_type=token**
После авторизации браузер будет перенаправлен на адрес следующего вида:

```
http://example.com/oauth/receiver#
refresh_token=b45529ac9bf6b32be761975c043ef9e3&
access_token=b6442ed12223a7d0b459916b8ea03ce5&
token_type=bearer
```

Comment: Так в том-то и дело! Я перечитал уже все мануалы касаемо mail.ru и проверил несколько раз на соответствие протоколу OAuth,  да и другие соц сети по этому принципу работают нормально, а вот с этой беда. Но за помощь спасибо!

Comment: @AlexandrKiseloy а возможности проверить не на локальной машине имеется? Просто на данный момент судить что-либо не имеет целесообразности, потому что проверяется все на локальной машине и работает скорее всего некорректно.

Comment: На сайте mail.ru требуется: https://oauth.mail.ru/login?.....
allauth же отсылает на страницу: https://connect.mail.ru/oauth/authorize?...
Не знаю пока, как это можно поправить?

Answer (score 0):

mail.ru не могут сделать несколько полей для URL сайта, например чтобы можно было поставить один продакшн а другой локалхост
читайте здесь https://my.mail.ru/community/myplatform/7DE49B6937BC56F6.html
Т.е. редирект должен совпадать с адресом сайта. А зарегистрировать приложение на локалхост тоже нельзя например на http://localhost:5000 у меня не получилось, поэтому приходится создавать приложение с нормальным адресом, потом менять его на локалхост. Короче это полное мракобесие во всем нормальном интернете сделано, чтобы можно было несколько URL добавлять, но это же mailru, полная деревня.

Comment: без перехода на личности пожалуйста

Comment: Ник по случаю такой стоит или нет?) проще всего прописать в хостс